# Replacing characters in a dataframe text column

Tags: dataframe, text

Please bear with me as I am new to dataframes.  I have a column of text in a dataframe that I would like to replace.  The issue is that I need to identify any fields with the string "PR" in the third to last and second to last characters and replace with a dash ("-"), then I would like to append the string ".US".  I also would like to replace any field containing a blank in the third to last character with a period (".").  So, given the the 'Name' column containing:

ABCPRL

ABC US

I would like to see:

ABC-L.US

ABC.US

I initially tried iterating through the rows of the dataframe but couldn't get it to work right.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can use pandas library in python to parse that, might search for that.

Comment: For this you will want to use the string accessor methods, shown here: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#api-series-str. Think of these accessor methods like ways of working with a single `str` object, except instead of working with an atomic `str` you're actually working with a whole column of `str` in your pandas series/dataframe column. For the replacement part use the `.str.replace` method with a regex. For adding to the end part,  I think you'll use the `str.cat` method or you can use `.str.replace` again and just match the end of the string.